# What class in Hibernate generates the SQL statements that gets logged?

Tags: hibernate, debugging

I'm having trouble with an `ObjectNotFoundException` where Hibernate appears to be performing a `select` statement where I didn't expect it too, due to lazy loading being true. I suspect something to do with AOP, but I can't change anything since I'm using someone else's framework.

I was thinking of putting a breakpoint in the place where the select statement gets generated into my log, that way I can see who's triggering it. What's the Hibernate class I should be setting breakpoints on?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe that the log entry is generated within [org.hibernate.jdbc.util.SQLStatementLogger](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/jdbc/util/SQLStatementLogger.html)

Answer (score 5):

Up until Hibernate line `3.6.x`, the class FQN was: [org.hibernate.jdbc.util.SqlStatementLogger](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/jdbc/util/SQLStatementLogger.html).

Starting with line `4.x`, at least till `5.2` the class is: [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/spi/SqlStatementLogger.html)

Answer (score 4):

Hell is other people's frameworks. You can see Hibernate logging its SQL if you configure log4j to get debug-level logging for org.hibernate.SQL and trace-level logging for org.hibernate.type. But Hibernate's SQL generation happens a long way from where it decides what it needs to do, so I doubt that will help. The SessionImpl has an ActionQueue that lists the actions Hibernate will take, you may want to watch what gets shown there.

Comment: Thanks, I watched both the actionQueue and SQLStatementLogger, and I now have something to write in my bug report to the other guy :D